# Copy text after line 7 and column 36 txt

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy the text `FINGER:PRINT:DATA` that is after line 7 and column 36, from a file named `temp.txt` to a new file.

The file looks like this:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

tes, Jan 10, 2019, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): FINGER:PRINT:DATA
```

Comment: presuming you have loaded the text into `$InStuff`, this otta work >>> `(($InStuff -match 'certificate')[0] -split ': ')[1].Trim()` <<<

Comment: [SO] isn't a script writing service, so what have you tried so far and didn't work? It's quite trivial, but PowerShell has many ways to do a task: `$fingerprint = ((Get-Content .\temp.txt -Tail 1 ) -Split '\): ')[1]`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the best solution, but will work in your case

```
(Get-Content C:\tmp\file.txt).split()[-1]
```

Just split your file and print the last item (or store the output in a file)

```
(Get-Content C:\tmp\file.txt).split()[-1] > file.txt
```

Comment: I'd change `> file.txt` to `| Out-File file.txt` so you have a pure Powershell solution.